# How to create dynamic drop down using formik in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am receiving this json Response From API.

```
{
    "1": "Suits",
    "2": "Sarees",
    "3": "Footmats",
    "4": "Carpets",
    "5": "Sofa Covers"
}
```

I want to take this json and display it in a drop down using formik

```
// Setting State
state = {
        itemType: {
            key: 0,
            value: 'Select'
        }
}

// Calling API in component did mount
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/itemTypes')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                itemType: response.data
            });
            this.createItemType();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

// filling options values for drop down
createItemType = () => {
    let items = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.itemType)) {
        items.push(<option key={key} value={key}>{value}</option>);
        //here I will be creating my options dynamically
    }
    return items;
}

// I have this field component to create drop down in <Formik> <Form> tag.
<Field name="itemType" className="form-control" component="select" placeholder="Item Type">
    {this.createItemType}
</Field>
```

My aim is to create dynamic values drop down like this

[image]

**What I am getting on screen is**
[image]

No drop down, only values gets printed.

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Why do you want to use a `Map`?

Comment: As I am from java world in that I was used to create a dynamic drop down using map. Ok there is no restrictions I can use anything.

Comment: Oh, I've jut posted an answer and it seems lots of things changed :)

Comment: Thanks Mate! This is also very helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You receive the error message because your `Field` component is an `input` field by default which can't have children. If you want it to be a `select` element, you can use the `as` prop:

```
<Field
  className="form-control"
  as="select"
  onChange={this.onItemTypeDropdownSelected}
  name="itemType"
>
  <option>...</option>
</Field>
```

You mentioned in a comment that it's not really necessary to use Map, the only reason you wanted that is because you're coming from Java. If your keys are strings (as in your example), you can use plain objects instead of Map. If you want to use Map however, you can convert a JSON object like this for example:

```
function objToMap(obj) {
  let map = new Map();

  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    map.set(key, value);
  }

  return map;
}
```

Edit: As you're no longer using Map, I've updated the snippet below:

```
state = {
  itemTypes: {},
};

componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get('/itemTypes')
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        itemTypes: response.data,
      });
      // you don't use this.createItemType() here 
      // just iterate over the state.itemTypes in render
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

render() {
  const options = [];
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.itemTypes)) {
    options.push(
      <option key={key} value={key}>
        {value}
      </option>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Field
      className="form-control"
      as="select"
      onChange={this.onItemTypeDropdownSelected}
      name="itemType"
    >
     {options}
    </Field>
  }
```

Comment: {for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.itemTypes)) {
    return <option key={key} value={key}>{value}</option>
  }}

It is giving syntax error on for loop mate!

Comment: Please can you explain why it was giving syntax error. For my understanding.

Thanks its working now.

Comment: I think it's because you need JSX or an array of JSX elements, and the original `for` loop didn't return an array. Now we insert `options` which is an array. In React, we usually use arrays and arrays of objects, and use array.map() to create a new array of elements. It's been a long time since I had to use a `for` loop in `render` and well... absolutely forgot you can't do that :)